# Find the number of permutations of the set $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7\right\}$ not containing four consecutive elements of ascending order

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of permutations of the set $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7\right\} $ not containing four consecutive elements of ascending order.

**My try:**

All permutations in cycles are $6!$. 
Let's deal with cases that do not meet the requirements of the task:

- When four growing elements are not at the beginning:

   - choice of beginning: ${3 \choose 1}$

   - choice of four numbers ${6 \choose 4}$

   So: $${3 \choose 1}\cdot {6 \choose 4}\cdot 2!=90$$
- When four growing elements are at the beginning:

   $${6 \choose 3}\cdot 3!=120$$

  Then we must count cases common to the previous two considerations: $${6 \choose 4}\cdot2!=30$$That is why my answer is: 
  $$6!-90-120+30=540$$
  However I wrote a Python program to check the number of solutions and he says it's $342$ so I have a mistake.
  Can you help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't mentioned that the permutation is cyclic. It looks as if it isn't from the question.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I'm just not sure how to receive cyclicality here because there is no mention of it in the content

Comment: not containing "exactly four" or not containing "four or more" consecutive elements?

Comment: @samerivertwice: If a permutation has $5$ consecutive terms in ascending order, then it certainly has $4$ consecutive terms in ascending order. Hence if a permutation does not contain $4$ consecutive terms in ascending order, then it does not contain $5$ consecutive terms in ascending order.

Comment: @quasi agreed, but you make the assumption (which I have next to no doubt is correct) that this asker has a precision which we know some askers not to have.

Comment: @samerivertwice: Which is exactly why I wouldn't ask it of the OP. Why offer the chance to muddle the issue? Instead, I would take the natural interpretation from the problem itself.

Comment: Your post is confusing. Your question is asking one problem (to which quasi [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325014/318073) correctly), but your attempt is solving another different problem (to which BallBoy [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325170/318073) correctly). This is confusing. Can you edit your post so it asks one clear intended question? And it wouldn't hurt for you to include the python code if you mentioned it, since it is clearly faulty. Here is mine that I used to verify the answers: [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FortunateUnwelcomeBrowser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of permutations of the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ which have $4$ consecutive terms in ascending order.

- The number of elements of $A$ whose first $4$ terms are ascending is
  $$\binom{7}{4}{\,\cdot\,} 3!=210$$
  Explanation:

  - There are ${\large{\binom{7}{4}}}$ choices for the first $4$ terms.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $3!$ ways to order the $3$ remaining terms.

  $\\[2pt]$

  The number of elements of $A$ whose initial block of $4$ consecutive ascending terms are not the first $4$ terms, and which start with the value $1$ is 
  $$\binom{6}{3}{\,\cdot\,} 3{\,\cdot\,} 3!=360$$
  Explanation:

  - There are ${\large{\binom{6}{3}}}$ choices for the $3$ terms which follow the value $1$.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $3$ positions where the value $1$ can be placed.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $3!$ ways to order the $3$ remaining terms.

  $\\[4pt]$

  The number of elements of $A$ whose initial block of $4$ consecutive ascending terms are not the first $4$ terms, and which start with the value $2$ is 
  $$\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{3}{\,\cdot\,} 3{\,\cdot\,} 2!=120$$
  Explanation:

  - There are ${\large{\binom{5}{1}}}$ choices for the term immediately before the value $2$.$\\[2pt]$

    There are ${\large{\binom{4}{3}}}$ choices for the $3$ terms which follow the value $2$.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $3$ positions where the value $2$ can be placed.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $2!$ ways to order the $2$ remaining terms.

  $\\[4pt]$

  The number of elements of $A$ whose initial block of $4$ consecutive ascending terms are not the first $4$ terms, and which start with the value $3$ is 
  $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}{\,\cdot\,} 3{\,\cdot\,} 2!=24$$
  Explanation:

  - There are ${\large{\binom{4}{1}}}$ choices for the term immediately before the value $3$.$\\[2pt]$

    There are ${\large{\binom{3}{3}}}$ choices for the $3$ terms which follow the value $3$.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $3$ positions where the value $3$ can be placed.$\\[2pt]$

    There are $2!$ ways to order the $2$ remaining terms.

  $\\[2pt]$

hence we get
$$|A|=210+360+120+24=714$$
so the number of permutations of the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ which do not have $4$ consecutive terms in ascending order is
$$7!-|A|=7!-714=4326$$

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't answer the OP's question, which was "Can you help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?" This presents an entirely new approach and makes no reference to the OP's attempt.

Comment: @Y. Forman: You're entitled to your opinion (and your downvote), but$\;(1)\,{:}\;$I'm doing a case analysis along the same lines as the OP's attempt, but using cases that have the chance of achieving successful counts, and$\;(2)\,{:}\;$In my opinion, trying to take apart the OP's hard to comprehend argument would be less helpful than showing a more understandable and potentially reusable approach.

Comment: Yeah, I agree the OP's argument is hard to comprehend, and I would encourage keeping your answer and just adding a sentence or two at the beginning explaining what you just explained in that comment.

Comment: I think it's better to leave it as is.

Comment: And you're entitled to do that, of course :) I'll keep the downvote in place then -- it's not meant as an attack on your mathematics or any kind of personal attack, it's just that if I were the OP and asked for help on something I had tried, I would be incredibly frustrated if someone answered the question without relating even briefly to my attempt.

Comment: That's fine with me. Of course you could have waited to see how the OP would assess my answer, but no worries.

Comment: Downvotes are not permanent. If the OP weighs in positively, I will strongly consider removing.

Comment: Not correct. Votes are locked after a short period unless I edit my answer, but in any case, the downvote doesn't phase me.

Comment: Interesting! I never knew that. I've downvoted several times to encourage changes to an answer and I guess the answerer always edited or I decided to change my vote within the short period. Thank you for educating me! In that case I do apologize for casting the downvote before the OP weighed in, and I hope you can forgive me.

Comment: Leave it! It accurately expresses your true opinion of the value to the OP of my answer.

Comment: Feel free to downvote my perhaps quixotic attempt to muddle through the OP's work.

Comment: No, go right ahead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to relate to the question how I think you understood it, even though I think quasi's read is much more straightforward.

(If I'm reading your answer correctly, you're considering cyclic permutations and fixing "the beginning" at $1$.)

You haven't accounted for all the overcounting. Any case with $5$ ascending elements starting not at the beginning has been counted twice in the first step. By your method, there are $2\binom651!=12$ such cases, so we must add $12$.

Then there are the $5$ cases in which exactly $6$ elements appear in order (starting from $1$, with anything other than a $7$ omitted) and the $1$ case in which all appear in order. The former cases were subtracted $3$ times each, then added $2$ times each, so no further correction is needed. The latter case was subtracted $4$ times then added $3$ times, so again no correction is needed.

So the answer should be $552$. I don't know how you got $342$ -- perhaps you can post the Python code?